# How to create commerce store resolver using user proximity / location

Tags: commerce, location

For a custom store resolver using store location proximity to user location, is it necessary to create a completely separate module or can the custom resolver be located somewhere within the commerce core module structure?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question does not fit the Drupal Answers format. Stack Exchange sites operate on a strict 1:1 question:answer format, with each topic being a single question, inviting single answers. The format of your question invites open discussion. If this topic gets shut down as a result (which is likely), this type of question would fit the format of the Drupal forums much better.

Comment: I realize now I've posted two questions here.  Regarding user location, that is resolved, possibly one additional step just to save user location for future reference but that's straightforward.  Also, I have stored the locations of the warehouses and so it is possible to compare user location to warehouse location.  Simplifying my question, how can I create a custom store resolver so that the resolver is used?  Do I need to create a complete separate module or can I include just the custom resolver somewhere within the commerce core module structure?

Comment: @DaveTown Please update your question to be in accordance with the 1 question - 1 answer guideline.

Comment: @berliner - updated, thanks for the guidance